# Replicate a row with modification in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like the following :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1,1,2,2,2,3], 'year': [2017, 2018, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2018], 'count': [1,2,2,3,4,1]})
```

and I would like to replicate the ID such that each ID is associated to the years 2017,2018 and 2019. Here the output I am expecting :

```
df_i_want =  pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3], 'year': [2017, 2018, 2019, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2017, 2018,2019], 'count': [1,2,np.nan,2,3,4,np.nan,1,np.nan]})
```

Do you have a solution? Thanks by advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for all combinations of columns:

```
df1 = (df.set_index(['ID','year'])['count']
          .unstack()
          .stack(dropna=False)
          .reset_index(name='count'))
```

Or [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html):

```
#if want specify years by list
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['ID'].unique(), [2017, 2018, 2019]], names=['ID','year'])
#if want all unique years
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['ID'].unique(),df['year'].unique()], 
df1 = df.set_index(['ID','year']).reindex(mux).reset_index()
print (df1)

   ID  year  count
0   1  2017    1.0
1   1  2018    2.0
2   1  2019    NaN
3   2  2017    2.0
4   2  2018    3.0
5   2  2019    4.0
6   3  2017    NaN
7   3  2018    1.0
8   3  2019    NaN
```

Comment: Love this logic, reshaping gives you great versatility :)

Answer (score 0):

In a few lines of code:

```
aux = df.groupby(['ID'],as_index=True).first()
aux['count'] = np.NaN
aux = aux.reset_index()
pd.concat([df,aux]).reset_index(drop=True)
```